# install package from a requirenment txt and failed

Tags: ubuntu

I read the rnn tutorial in https://github.com/dennybritz/rnn-tutorial-rnnlm and follow the installations to set up the environment. But I got the error which I have no idea about this. I set up it in `virtualenv` in Ubuntu 14. I have search the similar problem and use their solution but it does not work.

The method I have tried: 
1. update `gcc`
2. reinstall `python-dev`
3. install `libxxx`(sorry about this inaccurate name but there are a mess of such files so I can not remember)

Note: 1. I am not an expert in ubuntu so if you can help me and hope you can provide a detailed explanation or solution if you are avaible.
2.I have tried to reinstall ubuntu and it does not work

```
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_RL_CALLBACK -DHAVE_RL_CATCH_SIGNAL -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_DISPLAY_MATCHES_HOOK -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_SUPPRESS_APPEND -DHAVE_RL_PRE_INPUT_HOOK -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Modules/2.x/readline.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o

In file included from Modules/2.x/readline.c:31:0:

./readline/readline.h:385:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

 extern int rl_message ();

 ^

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o readline/libreadline.a readline/libhistory.a -lncurses -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gnureadline.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/shuyu-lyu/venv/build/gnureadline/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xF2y3k-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/build/gnureadline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shuyu-lyu/venv/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/shuyu-lyu/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/shuyu-lyu/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 66: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ncurses library is not installed. If you are on Ubuntu, you should first install it with

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
```